# bitbucket remove one user's write access

Tags: bitbucket

I grant a friend with write access to my project on bitbucket. 
But now, he wants to quit but want to remain a read access to view how I'm going with my codes.

I looked through some pages I googled, but didn't find how to change his access from 'write' to 'read'.

Please tell me how I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

The link above is now dead, so at present you can edit user groups by clicking on your profile image at the top right then Bitbucket Settings, select your team from the dropdown next to the word "Settings" on the left, then click "User Groups" under Access Management on the left-hand menu.